# Flutter TextFormField onFieldSubmitted will not raise in case of the user itself tap the next field

Tags: flutter, textformfield

Building Flutter form with TextFormField shown below:

```
TextFormField(
 onFieldSubmitted: (value) => {
  if (value == "Something") {
    debugPrint("Something should happen!"),
  },
 ),
```

I want the onFieldSubmitted to fire whenever a user leaves this field (click somewhere else, press tab, etc).

Unfortunately, this example only fires IF the user presses the checkmark SUBMIT button on the keyboard - which most people probably won't do.

How can I make this code fire whenever a user leaves this TextFormField?

Thank you!

Comment: Check the [docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextFormField/TextFormField.html), try `onTapOutside`, `onEditingComplete` etc. to see which works for you.

Comment: For what it's worth I'd also be interested in a comprehensive solution to this.